# Google Form input validation via script before submission?

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api, google-forms

I have a form currently set up and I am wanting to link validation between 2 options. For example, we ask for a phone number. If they mistype their number, we don't know which one to dial or use. I was wondering if there was a script that will read their responses and check that they entered the same data into 2 certain boxes, so that if the boxes don't match, they get an error when they click submit to go back and check that their data matches.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to add scripting behavior to a Google Form that runs when the form is being *filled out*. It's only possible to add scripting when the form is being created/edited or after it's been submitted.